# Objective-C @property variables for an object of class

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, subclass

In my code i declare an `@property` for my Main class in my sub class to set values there

```
@property(nonatomic,retain)  MainViewController *father;
```

but i noticed that `retain` make the `dealloc` method not called in my main class, but when i change it to:

```
@property(strong, nonatomic)  BabyViewController *father;
```

the `dealloc` method returned to be called.

i did this without knowing if that effect my code performance or not.

i used this `property` to do this in my main class:

```
    subClass* controller = [[subClass alloc] initWithPageNumber:page];
    controller.father=self;
    [controller.view removeFromSuperview];
```

is this the best i can do ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better you can use `assign` property for the declaration of `viewControllers` and `delegates`.It will assign the data and won't `dealloc` the variable. So use like this,

```
@property(nonatomic,assign)  MainViewController *father;
```

Comment: Thank you, The dealloc method is called with your code as i want